# Position div under an absolutely positioned div with a responsive height

Tags: css, absolute

I'm trying to position my navigation under a css slideshow (which isn't finished yet). The slideshow is positioned absolutely so my nav is shooting to the top of the window. How can I force the navigation under the slideshow when the images' heights are responsive to the width of the window?

Answer (score 0):

If the slideshow you're making is custom code and not some plugin, I have a suggestion. Inside the slideshow you can put a div, give it position relative, and then put your nav inside that div. The nav would be position absolute and give it "bottom: n px;" where n is the height of your nav. Hope that makes sense!

Comment: I think matty-d means [something like this](http://jsfiddle.net/CRALj/1/). Where the nav (black area) will be moved down depending on the slideshow's (red area's) height